# ng-repeat with a newline on every third repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want 10 buttons representing digits.
super easy, just ng-repeat 0-9 and i have it.

How do I make it look like this:

```
789
456
123
```

instead of 0123456789

something like 'for every third repeat create a new line' ??

All I can think of is something like:

```
{{ x == 3 || 6 || 9 ? return "<br>" }}
```

but there is probably a more logical approach. I'm new to this all

Comment: Seems like you're looking for the modulo operator `{{ x%3 === 0 ? return "<br>" }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of

`ng-repeat="dinosaur in [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]"`

on your element and if using bootstrap make each element have class .col-xs-4 which should cause them to wrap every 3.  Another option might involve a

```
ng-if="!($index%3)"
```

which would show the element every third item.

Comment: two solutions ! hahahaha thanks man
For some stupid reason I did not even THINK of using bootstrap, even though my whole app is inside bootstrap

and I learned something new. the modulo is something I never used before. Will play with this a bit too. thanks everyone

Comment: Okay, but what if our collection is an array of objects? Sticking to `item` won't do any magic though answers is correct in the scope of array of numbers.

Comment: Item is just a variable name I could call it dinosaurs and it would work :)

Comment: I don't complain about the name :) But I do for conditional statement. It looks not really correct. For example, it will fail because it starts of "!" without any brackets ;) So it will be executed like this: `( ( ! item ) % 3 )`. So... It should be at least `!(item%3)`. But perfect answer would be `!($index%3)`.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks I will edit, iPhone from bed not the greatest text editor.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that I covered the whole question.

Given: 0123456789

Solution:

`$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : item : true">
    <br ng-if="!($index % 3)" />
</span>
```

This can make a trick.

Third argument of "orderBy" will reverse the order and the goal is to check the `$index` which is an iterator inside `ng-repeat` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Something Like:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
   <span>{{i}}<span> 
   <span ng-if="!(i%3)"> <br/><span>
</span>
```

Happy Helping!